# How to fix different result in python programming

Tags: python, numpy, overflow

I try to show poisson distribution using scipy, numpy.

poisson distribution is defined:

```
exp(-lambda) * (lambda^k)/k!
```

k is random variable ranging from 0 to 255 and lambda is parameter chosen 25.

```
x = np.linspace(0, 255, 256)
(np.exp(-lambda)*np.power(lambda,x))/scipy.misc.factorial(x)
```

[result in debugging monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mszs.png)

[plot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaGUH.png)

from above figures it looks like good result...

However if I calculate it with single value not a using linspace, all of the results are zero.
For example

```
x = 20
(np.exp(-lambda)*np.power(lambda,x))/scipy.misc.factorial(x)
```

result = 0...

But previous result using linspace has 0.00886

Comment: What Python version?

Comment: hmm i cannot seem to replicate your error in both python2 and python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some times the most obvious solution can be right in front of us and still be invisible to the developer.

Try doing:

```
x = 20
(np.exp(-lambda)*np.power(lambda,x))/scipy.misc.factorial(x * 1.0)
```

We multiply the x by 1.0 to "convert" it to a float so the division can do decimals correctly

Comment: i think the numerator already evaluates to a float, so it might not make a difference. but well, worth a shot for OP!

Comment: @Floaterz
Thank you. I retry to put value 20.0 instead of 20. It works!
Can you explain more detail why this happen?

Comment: In my experience as a programmer when ever I try to do a multiplication and want some precision with the result I always try to have in the formula some number with x.0 This means the compiler will treat it as a float and the main result will lead to a more precise measurement. 

Example: 

1 / 2 = 0

but 

1.0 / 2 = 0.5
or 
1 / 2.0 = 0.5

If the equation does not contain any float number, the main result will always floor the result, so 5.7 becomes 5 and 0.5 becomes 0. On the other hand, having a float solves this issue